# Erro quando digito o comando php artisan migrate no terminal do windows

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

**Erro:** após digitar o comando `php artisan migrate` no *Windows*:

> Microsoft Windows [versão 6.2.9200] (c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation.
>   Todos os direitos reservados.
>
> C:\Users\x538238>cd C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel>php artisan migrate
>
> In Connection.php line 664:
>
> could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
>   where t   able_schema = teste and table_name = migrations)
>
> In Connector.php line 67:
>
> could not find driver
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel>composer update 'composer' não é reconhecido
>   como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo
>   em lotes.
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel>

Comment: Veja [nessas perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=could+not+find+driver) se não encontra algo que te ajude.

Answer (score 0):

**Sobre o drive** você precisa habilitar que drive de banco de dados está utilizando, isso precisa ser habilitado no seu xampp.

**Composer**

Baixe e instale o composer no seu windows
https://getcomposer.org/download/
Obs.: Note que ao instalar existe uma opção para você selecionar o caminho do PHP.EXE

Comment: Precisa habilitar qual? É no arquivo php.ini? Pq se for, eu já habilitei e não resolve do mesmo jeito

Comment: Sobre o composer eu não consigo instalar na minha máquina, pq eu uso proxy da empresa, e tá com problema